# Comparing message strings in custom warnings.showwarning

Tags: python, python-3.x, warnings

I am attempting to perform a custom action when I see a very specific warning. The warning is a `UserWarning` with the message `'Skipping SYSTEM_VARIABLE record'`. I want all other warnings, including all other `UserWarning`s with different messages, to be propagated and printed to `stderr` as usual.

The only way I could find to do this is to replace [`warnings.showwarning`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.showwarning) with a custom implementation, as in the following test script:

```
import warnings

def showw(message, category, filename, lineno, file=None, line=None):
    print(message, category, filename, lineno, file, line, sep='|')
    print(message == 'Skipping SYSTEM_VARIABLE record')
    print(category == UserWarning)
    if category == UserWarning and message == 'Skipping SYSTEM_VARIABLE record':
        print('Doing a thing here')
    else:
        original(message, category, filename, lineno, file=file, line=line)

original = warnings.showwarning
warnings.showwarning = showw

warnings.warn('Skipping SYSTEM_VARIABLE record')
```

This script prints out the following output:

```
Skipping SYSTEM_VARIABLE record|<class 'UserWarning'>|x.py|15|None|None
False
True
x.py:15: UserWarning: Skipping SYSTEM_VARIABLE record
  warnings.warn('Skipping SYSTEM_VARIABLE record')
```

I find this output surprising because the first line indicates that the message is in fact `'Skipping SYSTEM_VARIABLE record'`, so the second line should read `True`, and the `if` rather than the `else` should be executed. However, it seems that the two strings are not identical for some reason.

Why is this happening? Why is the "custom action" `print('Doing a thing here')` not being triggered?

I have tried replacing all three occurrences of `'Skipping SYSTEM_VARIABLE record'` with just `'a'` in the script to eliminate the possibility of a typo. The exact same result happens.

I am using Python 3.5.2 on Anaconda 2.4.0 on a CentOS 7 server, so str vs. unicode should not be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the answer on a hunch a couple of minutes after posting:

The reason that the comparison fails is that `message` is not a string, but the actual warning object, whose string representation (via `str`) happens to just be the warning message.

An additional printout, `print(type(message))` demonstrates this fact:

```
<class 'UserWarning'>
```

The correct comparison is `str(message) == 'Skipping SYSTEM_VARIABLE record'`.

The only reason that I am keeping this question and answer around is that there does not appear to be anything in the documentation of [`warnings.showwarning`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.showwarning) to explicitly describe this behavior.